# No cambiar el tamaño de la imagen "onError" javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagen

Tengo una imágen que se carga correctamente pero si la ruta/imágen no existe, carga otra estándar.

La imágen estándar no tiene el mismo tamaño que las originales por tanto, si se estira se ve borrosa. Lo que necesitamos es que si se carga la imágen del "onError", mantenga su tamaño y no cambie, pero las otras si. Es decir, tenemos este código:

```
return '<img src="' + ruta + '" alt="usuario" width="64" height="89" onerror="this.src=\'../Fotos/receptionist2.png\'" />';
```

Queremos que si se carga la imagen correcta, el ancho y alto sea 64*89, pero si se carga la imagen estándar no queremos que se cambie el tamaño, es decir, queremos que mantenga su tamaño y no haga caso al width y height.

He probado a hacerlo con jquery pero no me funciona.

Este es el código jquery (aviso: soy muy novato en jquery. Posiblemente esto sea una locura lo que he hecho):

```
var src = $('img[alt="usuario"]').attr('src');

if(src === ruta){
    $('img[alt="usuario"]').width(64);
    $('img[alt="usuario"]').height(89);
}else{
    $('img[alt="usuario"]').width() = $('img[alt="usuario"]').width();
    $('img[alt="usuario"]').height() = $('img[alt="usuario"]').height();
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Marcos, puedes añadir lo que has intentado en jQuery y los errores o problemas concretos? Mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es añadir una clase que establezca los valores de `width` y `height` a `auto` cuando se carga la imagen por defecto:

```js
function cargarImagenes(){
  var img1 = document.getElementById('imagen1');
  img1.onerror = cargarImagenPorDefecto;
  var img2 = document.getElementById('imagen2');
  img2.onerror = cargarImagenPorDefecto;
}

function cargarImagenPorDefecto(e){
  e.target.src= 'https://www.blackwallst.directory/images/NoImageAvailable.png';
  $(e.target).addClass('noimage');
}
cargarImagenes();
```

```css
img{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 89px;
}

img.noimage{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/458/PNG/128/Shy-Minion-icon_43752.png" id="imagen1" />
<img src="https://imagen-noexiste.com/noimage.png" id="imagen2" />
```